# Сыграть партию/сыграть в партию

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, словосочетания

Можно ли выражаться следующим образом: сыграть партию в теннис/шахматы/монополию или сыграть в партию шахмат, тенниса, монополии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильный только первый вариант, потому что "партию" можно перенести (предлог к ней не относится):
*Сыграть в теннис/шахматы/монополию (одну) партию*.

Разговорный вариант:
*Сыграть партию шахмат/тенниса/монополии.*

Comment: Добавила бы, что "партия" - это как "раунд" или "сет". Нельзя сыграть "в раунд" или "выиграть в сете".

Comment: Мне кажется, что "выиграть в сете" можно, как и "выиграть в раунде".

Comment: А в партии можно выиграть?

Comment: Нет, говорят "выиграл партию".

Comment: Если академически, то да — "выиграл раунд" (официальный результат). Но "*в этом раунде уже он выиграл*" звучит нормально. Разве нет? Вроде как разговорный вариант.

Comment: Но при этом фразы "он выиграл в раунде" и "он выиграл в сете" (без "этом") кажутся некорректными. А можно ли сказать "в этой шахматной партии он выиграл"? Мне кажется, как и с раундом, можно.

Comment: Да, не хватает слов, чтобы нормально звучало. *В этой шахматной партии он выиграл* — просто только слышал "выиграл партию", и у меня не звучит. Но наверное, можно, но думаю, что уровень разговорности здесь выше.